# MongoDB Data Model Design for Meteor.js App

Tags: mongodb, meteor, data-modeling, database

I'm not much of a backend guy and even worse when it comes to MongoDB, however, I've been taken with Meteor.js so I'm giving it a try as I play around.

I'm creating a project management/ticketing app and would like your opinion on the data model design. In my app you create a ticket, assign other team members to the ticket and allow people to access it and manipulate the data like a todo list, attachments, comments, etc. Pretty basic.

From my research, it appears that a normalized data model with references makes sense. In that case, is a good model:

1. A collection for all my users.
2. A collection for tickets (each ticket/project its own document) with a field for team members in which I insert them into an array using a reference. Then I'd have fields for comments, todos, etc.

Or would this be best:

1. A collection for all my users.
2. A unique collection for each ticket with a field for team members kept in an array.

Sorry if this seems rather basic. I'm taking the MongoDB University classes for Node, so I hope I don't have to rely on too many basic questions for too long.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You should store each ticket/project in its own document in a single collection (the first option).

If you give each ticket its own collection you have no effective way to index and query tickets.

Comment: Thanks Tomas! Would you add all the comments in an array in one field then?

Comment: Yes, the comments would be a single field, containing an array of objects. Each object would contain a username, date, message and other applicable fields.